# How to get separate data from AJAX response

Tags: laravel

Right now using this in the controller out of an AJAX post request.

```
$questpage = $request->input('input_object');
```

gives me this

```
name=test1&token=LEzN7VR2vib0pDegV9w1FasbZNc71pAbr4cUkuQ1
```

I would like to get name out of this result. I have tried stuff like 
  `$questpage->name` , or `$questpage = $request->input('input_object.1.name');`

Also, I'm generating a `csrf_token` in the input form and a different one in the AJAX POST. Is this OK?

Comment: Try yo generate your csrf token before or after the input, but not inside.

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate your `csrf_token` before or after the input, but not inside.

Like this :

```html
<form method="POST" action="/yourAction">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  {{csrf_token()}}
</form>
```

Comment: ok, so i removed the form input , and left the csrf of the ajax post. but im still getting 
name=sfdsf. and i would like to get the value of name, in this case sfdsf

Comment: Your HTML code seems good. Try to use `$request->get("name");` and please pastebin also the part where you try to get the input value

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$questpage = $request->input('input_object');

parse_str($questpage, $output);

$name = $output['name']; // test1


var_dump($output);

array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
        string(5) "test1"
    ["token"]=>
        string(40) "LEzN7VR2vib0pDegV9w1FasbZNc71pAbr4cUkuQ1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="/yourAction">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

you can echo name

```
$name = Input::get('name');
    print_r($name);
```